# Manually Sync between Google Chrome Tabs

Tags: google-chrome, sync

Synced tabs is a feature accessible through History (History > Tabs from Other Devices). It enables you to access tabs opened on Chrome app on your smartphone.

I'm trying to get Google Chrome on my Desktop to reflect the changes to the tabs. However, I can't find a way to manually update/sync, and the last sync is over half an hour ago. Is there a way to increase sync frequency or manually sync?

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto chrome://history/syncedTabs in your chrome browser
2. Click on   "Tabs from other devices" in the left menu
3. Then choose your desired device open tabs

Comment: Note: Clicking that link takes you to `https://chrome//history/syncedTabs` (which is incorrect), even though the author created the link correctly. So, you'll need to either 1) manually type `chrome://history/syncedTabs` into the address bar, or 2) click the 3 dots menu > History > History > "Tabs from other devices", or 3) `ctrl + H`, then "Tabs from other devices". I think Chrome doesn't allow you to link to `chrome://` destinations for security reasons.